# ¿Como recorrer un array de objetos usando *ngFor en angular 8?

Tags: angular

Muy buenas, a continuación les muestro como tengo el código de `ProductListComponent`

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// model
import { abc } from '../../../models/product';

// service
import { ProductService } from '../../../services/product.service';

// toastr
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  productList: abc[];


  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    return this.productService.getProducts()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(item => {
        this.productList = [];
        item.forEach(element => {
          let x = element.payload.toJSON();
          x["Mate"] = element.key;
          this.productList.push(x as abc);
          console.log(x);


        });
      });
  }

  onEdit(product: abc) {
    this.productService.selectedProduct = Object.assign({}, product);
    this.toastr.warning('Operacion Realizada', 'Edite Producto ');
  }

  onDelete(abc: string) {
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?')) {
      this.productService.deleteProduct(abc);
      this.toastr.error('Operacion Realizada', 'Producto borrado');
    }
  }

}
```

Así es como estoy obteniendo los datos:

```js
<tr *ngFor="let abc of productList, let i = index">
                    <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{abc.Mate}}</td>
                    <td>{{abc.clase}}</td>
                    <td>{{abc.edad}}</td>
                    <td>{{abc.nombre}}</td>

                </tr>
```

Estoy obteniendo los datos de [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) pero estoy obteniendo un array de objetos y el `*ngFor` me muestra object.

```js
ngOnInit() {

    return this.productService.getProducts()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(item => {
        this.productList = [];
        item.forEach(element => {
          let x = element.payload.toJSON();
          x["Mate"] = element.key;
          this.productList.push(x as abc);
          console.log(x);


        });
```

Desde aquí estoy recorriendo `Mate` que es mi `key`, y lo que sucede cuando muestro los datos en la web solo muestra object estoy usando `*ngFor` para imprimir, que me recomiendan hacer para imprimir en pantalla los arreglos de objetos que estoy obteniendo de [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) en tiempo real.

Comment: Por favor, muéstranos productList desde tu *.ts* ver tu html no nos da nada de información sobre por qué devuelve Object

Comment: Bien que hayas puesto el código del *.ts*.... Que estas usando? firestore o Realtime Database??